# Let K be a field, in SageMath

Tags: symbolic-math, algebra, sage

How can I construct something that's analogous to the beginning of a proposition with "Let K be a field" -- some kind of field that isn't defined, but does have an arbitrary field's properties.

I've seen this [symbolic ring](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/calculus/sage/symbolic/ring.html) documents page, but I am not sure if I can construct a symbolic ring that has .is_field() == True.

Can somebody help? I'd also be interested in doing the same for Let G be a group, or how one would go about more complicated symbolic algebraic objects, like let P be a PID.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SageMath, a generic field is represented by `sage.rings.ring.Field` ([source](https://github.com/sagemath/sage/blob/3880b4839764c8559262cdc0a90467eb809e0cbc/src/sage/rings/ring.pyx#L2052)/[docs](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings/sage/rings/ring.html#sage.rings.ring.Field)). Similarly, PIDs are represented in [`sage.rings.ring.PrincipalIdealDomain`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings/sage/rings/ring.html#sage.rings.ring.PrincipalIdealDomain), and groups in [`sage.groups.group.Group`](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/groups/sage/groups/group.html?highlight=group#sage.groups.group.Group).

Comment: But be aware that it might not come built in with too many implemented methods ...